# escaping the greater than and less than symbols in javascript

Tags: javascript

The code I have currently produces a html page with with "ac" on it, what I want is to have literally what the value of the string is (I would type it out here but I'm having the same problem). In words, what I want is "a" then the less than symbol then "b" then the greater than symbol then "c".

Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p id="output"></p>

<script>

document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "a<b>c"

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 7):

Set it as text instead of as html

```js
document.getElementById("output").textContent = "a<b>c"
```

```html
<p id="output"></p>
```

Or convert to html entities

```js
 var str = "a<b>c".replace('<','&lt;').replace('>','&gt;')
 document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = str;
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: `.replace('<','&lt;').replace('>','&gt;')` will only replace the first occurences of each tag. Need to use RegEx instead (see @Mamum's answer below).

Comment: use replaceAll to replace all instances of occurence.

Answer (score 6):

Try the following way:

```js
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "a<b>c".replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;')
```

```html
<div id="output"</div>
```